# Beamer and listings incompatible?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, listings

I suspect that listings and beamer are incompatible and I am looking for a fix.

My minimal example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\section{Sectionheadertext}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}[name=bla,caption={Testcaption},label=lst:op]
 var x = "Test";
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\lstlistoflistings
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem is: The second frame does not provide a list of listings (I would expect an entry with "Testcaption") but rather provides a list of section headers, i.e. "Sectionheadertext".

I am searching for a patch to fix this, since I need a list of listings in beamer.

Comment: Related: (looks like a lot of work...) [List of Figures + Beamer?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/56417)

Comment: \lstlistoflistings uses \tableofcontents and modifies \@starttoc to use the lol file.  However, beamers modifies \tableofcontents to not use \@starttoc.

Comment: Also, it appears the \writefile{lol} is missing a few entries.

Comment: @AlanMunn: I was able to adapt the stuff you link to and got that working for my special case.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog If you add your solution as an answer it would be helpful to others.

Comment: It is essentially the thing you pointed out with some minor layout adaption, which is not helpful to others but pulls in a bit of style specific to my own task.It really is pretty much straight forward and I can encourage everyone to just pick it up from there.